# How do we read webpages using WP7 Mango?

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, webclient

I'm trying to read a web page using WP7 using the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK (Mango). I have a URL which I would like to read and later perform some function on it. I tried using HttpWebRequest and WebClient but wasn't successful in obtaining a response. Any suggestions? Update: Find below the code I used. The issue is that I'm able to read just a partial response of the page.

```
    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(txtURL.Text); //txtURL loads URL
            var result = (IAsyncResult)request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseCallback, request); 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
        } 
    } 

    private static void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState; 
            var response = request.EndGetResponse(result); 

            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream()) 
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) 
            { 

                var contents = reader.ReadToEnd(); 

                textToBeDisplayed = contents; 
                if (textToBeDisplayed != "") 
                { 
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
                    { 
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(textToBeDisplayed); 
                    }); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
            { 
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
            }); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to retrieve data? Did you get any exception or HTTP status code? If yes which one.

Comment: There were no exceptions whatsoever. I get just a partial response from any URL that I provide.

Comment: Do you have an url which you tried? I have copied your code (only removed the static keyword from your private method) and can access an url and get the full page.

Comment: No, even after removing static, I navigate to google.com and all I get is less than half of the html markup on the page. I'm unable to add it to the comment here.

Comment: Can you use Fiddler to see what is in the actual response?

Answer (score 2):

```
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
 wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
 {
      string Html = e.Result;
 };
 wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://google.com"));
```

Comment: I'm still not able to download the html markup from the URL. With less code I get to download the same partial output. I use System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Html); to view the output of the string. Is there a mistake in doing that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine is the culprit. I added a breakpoint to my code and found that the entire html markup is available in the string. For some reason, System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine does not print the entire string. Thanks for the help.